# why I am not able to access rails localhost on my mobile or other computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I am trying to access my localhost of rails running project on my mobile device.

This is how I am trying.

```
http://ip:3000
```

But it says the webpage is not available.

I tried with another port as well and It doesn't work even there?

What's wrong here? I use to check earlier this way.

Please guide

Comment: your phone and server is on same network ?

Comment: Yes, on the same network

Comment: map your ip with local host on your hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give:

> ip = your phone's ip address

(Check it in connection information if you are running this on Ubuntu)

`ip:3000/your_page` if you do not have mapped your root to some page.

Else `ip:3000` will work if you have mapped root to some page.
Try it in Chrome and see as it doesn't need any http or https it automatically selects the required one.

Comment: Oh yes, this worked.. And after that I am able to go to index from
     ip:3000

Thanks

Comment: Wait, why would you put the phone's ip address? Is the phone hosting the application?

Comment: @Slicedpan In order to check the application on phone he has connected his machine with phone's network so in order to open the rails app on phone we have to use the same **ip address** which is provided by the phone. But in case if you want to open the page on your system browser then it can be opened using  _localhost:3000_.

Comment: Let me see if I have this right. let's say the server has ip 192.168.1.1 and the phone has ip 192.168.1.2, and you want to view the app on the phone, you enter 192.168.1.2:3000 in the phone web browser?

Comment: @slicedpan Yes because the rails app was locally hosted on the machine, it will not be accessible to the phone. But once you give  **192.168.1.2:3000** on your phone it becomes accessible, which is your phone's IP address. Just give it a try. If it is not locally hoted but hosted on a web server you will be able to access to it on phone using **192.168.1.1/your_page** instead of phone's _IP address_.

Comment: I have tried this before, the correct procedure is to ensure that the application server binds to all ip addresses as the other answer shows, and enter the ip address of *the server* in the phone's web browser. Entering the ip address of the phone it its browser will do nothing unless the phone itself has a web server installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78085/discussion-between-sahil-and-slicedpan).

Comment: So here's the thing, I am connected to my WIFI, running locally on port 3000, my mobile is connected to the same wifi.

When I am doing this, `192.168.1.136:3000/projects` This is not working again.

Comment: Is _192.168.1.136_  your **system's IP** address. Check the IP address in your system and replace it with your IP shown in system. @Suraj

Comment: @Sahil this is my system's ip.

Answer (score 6):

Try running this code below to your server:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it

1. Put both your computer and phone on the same wifi network
2. rails s -b 0.0.0.0
3. routerlogin.net (or however you access your router it will say on the back of router)
4. get attached devices to the router. Note your computers ip. Mine was 10.0.0.20
5. on phone go to 10.0.0.20:3000 (but use the ip for your computer from step 4)